# Why child theme css not updated?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a question about child theme CSS not being executed.

This is the child style.CSS

```css
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 Theme Name:   Sue Maisano
 Theme URI:    http://suemaisano.com
 Description:  This is a child Divi theme for SueMaisano.com
 Author:       Sue Maisano
 Author URI:   http://clickstosuccess.com
 Template:     Divi
 Version:      1.0.0
 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html

------------------------------ ADDITIONAL CSS HERE ------------------------------*/
```

This is the child functions.php

```html
<?php

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) die();

function ds_ct_enqueue_parent() { wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' ); }


function ds_ct_loadjs() {

 wp_enqueue_script( 'ds-theme-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/ds-script.js',

        array( 'jquery' )

    );

}


add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ds_ct_enqueue_parent' );

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ds_ct_loadjs' );

include('login-editor.php');

?>
```

What could be wrong that stops the child CSS being executed? The custom CSS part within the theme options works fine but I would rather keep all CSS work in the child theme CSS editor to keep it organized.

Thanks so much for any help!
Sue

Answer (score 0):

You have enqueud parent CSS only. Enqueue child CSS too:

```
function ds_ct_enqueue_parent() { 

wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

 }
```

Comment: Brilliant! Solved the issue. Thanks so much!

Comment: It worked for a few days with the addition of enqueued child CSS, and now it doesn't work again...